# Refresh include virtual .asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I do have a product page where I do have all my products.

In the top of this page I load the cart to be always visible from an external file

```
<!--#include virtual="header.asp" -->
```

I do want to have a button that when onclick refresh only this part of the page "header.asp" and not the whole page

I've tried with a

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

but it refresh the whole page, is there any way to refresh only the include header.asp page?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can use AJAX to reload data from the server, however note that how you achieve this is based entirely on your use case. It's not just a magic bullet to reload a SSI, you'll need to provide the data to the AJAX endpoint and handle updating the UI in your client side code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rory, can you give me a link or something where I can find more info? sorry but still not clear to me,

Comment: any other options? thanks!